# WooCommerce Removing Coupon Field From Cart For Specific Product

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a fatal error in a child theme's functions.php file around line 228. Here's the section. The purpose of the code is to hide the coupon field on the cart page when the customer is ordering a gift certificate.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled','ts_hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );
function ts_hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
$product_id = 2400;
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
foreach ( $cart as $id => $cart_item ) {
    if( $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_id() == $product_id ) {
        return false;
    }
}   

return $enabled;
}
```

Can anyone help me with fixing the error? It has been working fine, but we had an issue with an order this morning (completely unrelated) but somehow I think this error may be to blame. TIA.

7-14-20: An update, the error is still a problem for me. When updating to the latest WooCommerce version, the site threw a fatal error. I have now removed the code from the functions.php file. I am going to continue to troubleshoot it; any help would be appreciated.

As per the suggestion, here's the error:

[Tue Jul 14 14:37:27.117532 2020] [php7:error] [pid 18971] [client 2603:301b:2601:b100:1948:a111:c595:46d7:42976] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-content/themes/ketolicious/functions.php:228\nStack trace:\n#0 /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): ts_hide_coupon_field_on_cart(true)\n#1 /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-includes/plugin.php(206): WP_Hook->apply_filters(true, Array)\n#2 /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-coupon-functions.php(69): apply_filters('woocommerce_cou...', true)\n#3 /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/Assets.php(157): wc_coupons_enabled()\n#4 /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Assets::get_wc_block_data(Array)\n#5 /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-includes/plugin.php(206): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)\n#6 /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/Assets/AssetDataRegistry.php(136): app in /nas/content/live/ketoliciousllc/wp-content/themes/ketolicious/functions.php on line 228, referer: https://ketoliciousllc.com/wp-admin/themes.php

Comment: Could you please show the actual error message? You may want to try to debug yourself first to narrow the place where the error occurs, perhaps by printing some debug info in that supposed location.

Comment: Hi Palo, Thank you. I copied the error and was going to post it to my question, but it contains site-specific info and links. So I removed it. Unfortunately I have done as much troubleshooting as I can. But this error occurred when I was editing an order that came through incorrectly. So, it did not happen at the time of order placement. I'm going to close this and will pursue it if it happens again. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The error message says that the contents of the WC()->cart is null. I do not know what is WC(), and why WC()->cart should contain something relevant. In the worst case you can check if it is null and in that case just return some value directly. I do not know, maybe it is somehow related to missing a global declaration in your function? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thank you Palo for your input and for your responsiveness. I appreciate it. I will follow the link and see if I can figure anything out. I appreciate the input.